# TKinter. Tcl_AsyncDelete: cannot find async handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, odoo, odoo-15

I am running tkinter library in the Odoo15 for a specific purpose.

I have created a custom python interpreter to run python code inside odoo.
To handle user inputs i specially designed a concept and via tkinter i am taking inputs from user.

In a code there may be more than one inputs and so i need to open the window more than one time. for example taken one input, Entered, closed window and then repeat the same process till final user input.

So in that case, at some movement my server getting terminated with a runtime error:

Tcl_AsyncDelete: cannot find async handler
Aborted (core dumped)

can anyone guide me how can i resolve this please ?

```
import tkinter as tk
import gc
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x200+600+300')
name_var=tk.StringVar()
var_1 = ''
def submit():
    name=name_var.get()
    global %s
    var_1 = name
    root.destroy()
name_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Enter value', font=('calibre',10, 'bold'))
name_entry = tk.Entry(root,textvariable = name_var, font=('calibre',10,'normal'))
sub_btn=tk.Button(root,text = 'Submit', command = submit)
name_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
sub_btn.grid(row=2,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

when there is a line like  value = input("Enter value")
i am replacing that line with the above code to take user input.

Looking forward to hear on this .. thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The code above should work as expected.

Comment: This same code running fine for few times but when i am taking user inputs for different python code, at some movement the error is occuring that i mentioned above and the odoo server getting stopped.

Comment: @Thingamabobs I went through your profile and seems like you have great knowledge of tkinter.  i am suffering with a serious problem due to this issue and i am in need to fix this urgently,  i will be grateful if you can help me out to fix this issue please

Answer (score 0):

Without a minimal reproducible example it is more of a guessing than an answer.

But due to your request, I'll try my best guess. The information how you code this section below, can be crucial.

> In a code there may be more than one inputs
> and so i need to open the window more than
> one time. for example taken one input,
> Entered, closed window and then repeat the
> same process till final user input.

If you destroy the root window, the instance of `tkinter.Tk()` and you try to retrieve the users input (data located in tkinter) of the destroyed instance you could run into trouble. Instead of creating new instances of `tkinter.Tk` use `tkinter.Toplevel`. You could hide the root window in many ways. I.e with overrideredirect and transparency.

**TL;DR**

Make sure you use the same instance of `tkinter.Tk()` through out the whole session and or connect the new instance with your server and vice versa.

Hope it will work out for you, especially because I don't know about `odoo`.